# VB Net Regex pattern not matching, but tested in regex website fine

Tags: regex, vb.net

I have a long string I'm trying to find matches for as seen below. "uppercaseLine" represents the string to be searched. It's contents are not important as I have put the same string and same regex pattern into various testing sites and confirmed it does find a match. I obviously remove the double quotes from the string before testing. However, this always returns 0 matches in my program no matter what.

```
Dim pattern = "(\bFROM\b|\bJOIN\b)\s+""([^""]+)"""
Dim viewMatches As System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchCollection = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(uppercaseLine, pattern)
MsgBox(viewMatches.Count)
```

I've also tried

```
Dim rx As New Regex("(\bFROM\b|\bJOIN\b)\s+""([^""]+)""")
Dim matches As MatchCollection = rx.Matches(uppercaseLine)
```

But the count is still always zero. A snippet of the long string I'm searching is the following:

```
"JOB_HEADER" ."SHIPD_FLG" FROM "JOB_HEADER" "JOB_HEADER"  JOB
```

...to which you can see the FROM "JOB_HEADER" that should return a match.

When I do the following which is parse out a snippet of the text I'm searching, it does find it. I've used "" and \u0022. I don't understand because I'm pulling the test string from same source that isn't working.

```
    Dim rx As New Regex("(\bFROM\b|\bJOIN\b)\s+\u0022([^\u0022]+)\u0022", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
    Dim teststring = "JOB_HEADER"" .""SHIPD_FLG"" FROM ""JOB_HEADER"" ""JOB_HEADER"" JOB"
    Dim matcho As MatchCollection = rx.Matches(teststring)
```

[Image of the full string that I'm searching](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfx1f.png)

Comment: Replace the double quotes with, e.g., `\u0022` - Escaping the quotes should also work, not sure in VB.NET

Comment: Thanks @Jimi, unfortunately I did try that and it didn't help. I guess the string I'm comparing is the problem, but I'm having a hard time determining why. When I parse out just the bit that should match, it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hate quotes in strings so I do it this way,

```
    Dim patt As XElement = <t><![CDATA[(\bFROM\b|\bJOIN\b)\s+"([^"]+)]]></t>
    Dim rx As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(patt.Value, System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.Compiled)
    Dim test As XElement = <t><![CDATA["JOB_HEADER" ."SHIPD_FLG" FROM "JOB_HEADER" "JOB_HEADER" JOB ...to which you can see the FROM "JOB_HEADER" from]]></t>
    Dim matches As System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchCollection = rx.Matches(test.Value)
    Debug.WriteLine(patt.Value)
    Debug.WriteLine(test.Value)
    Debug.WriteLine(matches.Count)
    For Each m As System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match In matches
        Debug.WriteLine(m.Index)
    Next
```

Hopefully I got the pattern correct.  It did find two matches in the test string.  The general form of cdata is

```
<![CDATA[content]]>
```

Debug:

```
(\bFROM\b|\bJOIN\b)\s+"([^"]+)

"JOB_HEADER" ."SHIPD_FLG" FROM "JOB_HEADER" "JOB_HEADER" JOB ...to which you can see the FROM "JOB_HEADER" from

2
26
89
```

Comment: Thanks @dbasnett, I don't have any problems getting a match with that sample string even with the quotes or escape characters. The primary problem is when I try to search the larger string I'm using, which contains that sample string. I suppose there's something about the string (maybe size) that is breaking it? See my added image of the query I'm searching. It's like 19k characters long so I don't know how to include it in this post.

Comment: @PhillipGrekstas - If you use my code but search that string you don't find matches?  That string is not that long.

Comment: When I use your code and search that string, I do find matches. Inexplicably it finds 5 matches and returns bizarre indexes as well. But I never had a problem finding the match in my sample string I provided. 

The debug from running your code:

(\bFROM\b|\bJOIN\b)\s+"([^"]+)"

"JOB_HEADER" ."SHIPD_FLG" FROM "JOB_HEADER" "JOB_HEADER" JOB

5
173
294
1661
1687
1750

Comment: How would I go about passing a variable to this line instead of the static string. I'm new to XML and CDATA

Dim test As XElement = <t><![CDATA["JOB_HEADER" ."SHIPD_FLG" FROM "JOB_HEADER" "JOB_HEADER" JOB ...to which you can see the FROM "JOB_HEADER" from]]></t>

Comment: I was able to figure my last comment out with:

Dim test As New XElement("title", New XCData(reader.GetString(0)))

The problem ended up being with the quotes in the source string. It was all working when I manually put in double quotes. VB Net is being weird. But your XElement and CDATA example worked really well. Thank you so much

Comment: @PhillipGrekstas - if it was a function you wouldn't need to be put in the variable.